# simplifying $({\log_{2}(n)})^{5\log_{2}(n)}$

Tags: logarithms

I'm trying to solve this operation for a computer algorithms course practice set.
I originally assumed that $\log_2(n)^{\log_2(n^5)} = \log_2(n^5) = 5\log_2(n)$ But I know that's not correct.

Comment: Just looking at the graph it doesn’t look like it really simplifies well. Edit: wolfram alpha agrees with me

Comment: You can alternatively write it as $n^{5log_{2}(log{2}(n))}$ if that helps